# upstart: initctl: Unknown job

Tags: linux, upstart

I have a job that's perfectly normal:

```
> start c4-ha-policy ; stop c4-ha-policy
c4-ha-policy (start) waiting
c4-ha-policy (start) starting
c4-ha-policy (start) pre-start, process 1731
c4-ha-policy (start) spawned, process 1828
c4-ha-policy (start) post-start, process 1829
    main process 1828
c4-ha-policy (start) running, process 1828
c4-ha-policy (stop) running, process 1828
c4-ha-policy (stop) pre-stop, process 1956
    main process 1828
c4-ha-policy (stop) stopping, process 1828
c4-ha-policy (stop) killed, process 1828
c4-ha-policy (stop) post-stop, process 2023
c4-ha-policy (stop) waiting
```

now if I copy it and start that, it fails:

```
> mv c4-ha-policy test1
> start test1 
start: Unknown job: test1
```

If I move it back it works. It's like init didn't re-read the directory. How do I make it?

```
initctl --version
initctl (upstart 0.3.8)
Copyright (C) 2007 Canonical Ltd.
```

Thanks!

Comment: What directory are you in?

Answer (score 2):

All jobs *must* end in '`.conf`'. See `init(5)`. Are you sure c4-ha-policy isn't actually `/etc/init/c4-ha-policy.conf`?

Comment: Try this, its likely the problem.